# Div Images Side by Side

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

Good morning, I am trying to put 2 images, side by side within a div.

I have tried float left and float right, but to no success.

It works on a separate HTML page, but not when I add it to my current page.

very strange, but a simple resolution, but cannot see it...

Thanks

```css
#mikeimgs {
 width:70%;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
}
.img1 {
 margin-top:10px;
 float:left;
}
.img2 {
 margin-top:10px;
 float:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="mikeimgs" class="fluid">
<div class="fluid img1"><img src="file:///G-DRIVE mobile USB/STR Website/STRv1/August 2016/Mike-Vittiimg.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="200"/></div><div class="fluid img2"><img src="file:///G-DRIVE mobile USB/STR Website/STRv1/August 2016/Odyssey250.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="200"/></div>
</div>
```

[image]` with the page i'm trying to create.

Comment: something must be overriding your css

Answer (score 1):

The div containing the image should not have fluid class, additionally you do not need float left and float right, they both will be float left.

```css
#mikeimgs {
 width:70%;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
.img {
 margin-top:10px;
 float:left;
 width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mikeimgs" class="fluid">
<div class="img"><img src="file:///G-DRIVE mobile USB/STR Website/STRv1/August 2016/Mike-Vittiimg.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="200"/></div><div class="img"><img src="file:///G-DRIVE mobile USB/STR Website/STRv1/August 2016/Odyssey250.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="200"/></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code as it stands seems to run fine [here](http://www.bootply.com/f8od40pj8n). However there's no CSS provided for the **.fluid** class. Is it possible that this class is overriding your expected outcome?